# Hide public projects for specific roles in Redmine

Tags: redmine

We have bunch of projects in the company and several of them of interest to all employees are public so that anybody can post an issue there.

Now, we want to allow external consultants to access projects they are part of and I don't want them to see any projects they are not part of, including public ones. They are all under role "External Consultants". Its very hard for us to switch all public projects to private since our Redmine procedures are already defined with such projects in existence.

So, is there plugin or patch that will allow me to put external consultants to their projects and hide from them internal public projects ? For instance, permission under projects for a role such as "View public projects" that would be on by default would be one solution that plugin might provide.

Is there any other method to do this ? How hard would be to implement? I initially thought of having second Redmine instance for consultants but we don't want to maintain that scenario, and furthermore, we don't want to have projects on 2 places (syncing is possible but adds another level of complexity).